# Display related nodes with taxonomy hierarchy in a View

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, views

MY taxonomy is set up like:

```
* Parent term
    * Child term
```

I have a content type with a term reference so they can select the term it is associated with.

And I need a view that displays a result like:

```
* Parent term
    * Child term
        - Related node
        - Related node
        - Related node
* Parent term
    * Child term
        - Related node
```

Is this possible with drupal 7 Views 3?
I am able to relate nodes with only one level of taxonomy hierarchy, but not two. Every example I have come accross does not display related nodes with children terms, only with parent terms.
Any help would be appreicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this functionality through the use of two separate views combined into one. I could not find a way for Drupal to handle this out of the box. Essentially I am using one view to show the nodes related to the child terms, and using another view to bring in the *View displaying child related nodes* and sort it under the parent term.

The modules I used were: [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php), [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)

### **Create your taxonomy vocabulary**:

> ```
>  * Parent term
>      * Child term1
>      * Child term2
> ```

### **Create a content type**

Once created add a Entity Reference field of type *Term Reference* referencing your taxonomy vocabulary's children terms you have created. Create a handful of nodes.

### **Create a View Block displaying content (related Nodes)**

After creating the View Block of content (the content type with the reference, show fields, HTML list), include the fields you want to show for the *related node* and give that view a contextual filter of the Entity reference field you used for the content type. Simply set the settings of the contextual filter under **When the filter value is NOT available** to *Hide View*. You can optionally set the no results behavior as well.

### **Create a view displaying taxonomy terms (Master view)**

Create a view of taxonomy (HTML List, Show fields), add a relationship of **Taxonomy term: Parent term** and require this relationship. Add field `Taxonomy term: Term ID` and hide from display. Add field `taxonomy term: Name` and under the field setttings, set the relationship to *Parent*, then hide from display. Add field `Taxonomy term: Name` to display the name of the term. Finally add a `Global: PHP` field and under the **Output code** provide the following snippet:

```
<?php 
   $viewNodeDetail = views_get_view('YOUR_VIEW_BLOCK_MACHINE_NAME');
   $viewNodeDetail->set_arguments(array($row->tid));
   print $viewNodeDetail->preview('BLOCK_MACHINE_NAME');
?>
```

Under the view format settings set the **Grouping field Nr.1** to the `(Parent) Taxonomy term: Name`.

This will treat the view block as a field (the view block is the child term + node and the master view sorts by the parent term). This will give you an end result of:

> - Parent term
>
>   - Child term
>
>     - Related node
>     - Related node
>     - Related node
> - Parent term
>
>   - Child term
>
>     - Related node